# Reverse single replacement reaction

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

Is it possible using electrochemistry or some other method to reverse a typical single replacement reaction to go in the opposite direction.  For example, is it possible to take silver metal and copper nitrate to get copper metal and silver nitrate?  I would like to do this, because nitric acid is very expensive to ship, and I can easily buy both silver metal and copper nitrate.  I don't know how to isolate the silver the silver nitrate as it is formed because it will simply react with copper metal in a electrochemical cell.

Comment: Have you heard of an [electrolytic cell](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Core/Analytical_Chemistry/Electrochemistry/Voltaic_Cells/Electrochemical_Cell_Conventions#Electrolytic_Cell)?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know what electrolyte I could use for the silver half of the cell without polluting the product or causing side reactions.

Comment: Use copper sulfate as the electrolyte and do it in a solvent where copper sulfate is soluble but silver sulfate is not.